# Trouble Aligning Elements in html using span

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div id = "top">

    <div id="search_top"> 
        <span> Search: </span>
        <span> <form id= "search"> <input class = "search_textbox" type="text" name="ticker" value="" ></form> </span>
        <div class="arrow-right block"> </div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
#top{
    display:inline-block;
}

#search{
    float:left;
}


.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 0.6em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.6em solid transparent;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    border-left: 0.6em solid green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What I want is to have "Search" then the form then the "arrow-right". However, this all comes out on top of each other and I'm not sure why...

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to float the *children* of `#search`, e.g. `#search > * { float: left; }`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/T85bu/)?

Comment: @Jeroen, that worked, but part way.. they are not vertically aligned and vertical-align:middle didn't seem to work...

Comment: If you can re-order the HTML a little you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3z7gL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems in your html code, an unclosed `input`, a `form` *inside* a `span` tag, etc. If you fix those problems you'll get to something like this:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="search_top">
        <span> Search: </span>
        <form id="search">
            <input class="search_textbox" type="text" name="ticker" value="" />
        </form>
        <div class="arrow-right block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following CSS will achieve the alignments you want:

```
#top {
    display:inline-block;
}

#search_top > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 0.6em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.6em solid transparent;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    border-left: 0.6em solid green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M396R/) for a demo.